# Updating files bigger then 1GB?

Tags: c#, windows, linux, bandwidth

Currently I am using xdelta to make the update files and send only the difference of the user current application version but I would like to know if there are better ways or other ways to approch this sort of situation and the advices the community could give me.

Our application is written in C# and our webserver is running on Linux with apache httpd.

Using xdelta new patchs shrink to the size difference between old and new file so the updates vary between 10mb to 500 mb avoiding the need to re-upload those 1GB each time we change something.

1. What other options do I have that you could recommend me ?
2. What else should I consider in this case ?

PS: I am really at loss with this to be honest, this is the first updater app I have made and I really don't know if I am doing it right.

---

**if possible recommend open source or non-commercial applications**

Comment: Could you guys post about the close votes is it because of the small information ? if you can point out additional information you need to know I would be pleased to tell but at first sight this was what I thiked as a resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the minimal amount of information provided, I dont see a problem with your approach.  If you need to patch a 1GB file you need to patch a 1GB file.  I assume it is a data file and therefore needs to be that size?  Is there any way you could split it into files that don't often change to possibly further reduce your patch size?

Comment: +1 @Toby thanks for the answer. Well I have a few cutscenes that even if I split those it would ended up around 1GB size also some data packs with textures and things like that. The main portion of what I am looking for is a well documented patcher app or library.

Answer (score 0):

You might give bsdiff a try. It's the same thing as xdelta, with a somewhat different algorithm.

Getting started under Windows was not all that straighforward when I first tried (that may be different now, have not looked in a while), but once it worked, it worked ok.
My mileage is that compression runs about 10 times slower than xdiff (but, who cares...) and generates patches that are usually about half the size. Obviously your mileage will depend a lot on your data, but for me it's big win. If you have some spare time, you could always give it a try.

The abysmal compress time may be a deterrent in some situations, but for my situation the fact that the patches are half the size excuses for everything, I wouldn't care if generating a patch ran over the entire weekend, if only that reduced the size again.